# Overriding onOptionsItemSelected from SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Yesterday, I found a great library that allowed me to have a "facebook menu" with a button on the top left of an action bar which, when pressed, would slide in a menu of items from the left.

The problem is that I wish to make use of the ActionBarSherlock library as well to make sure that my application is backwards compatible with the action bar. When using the library I, among other things, need to override onOptionsItemSelected as such :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {

        rbmView.toggleMenu();

        return true;

    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Now I went into the library and saw that the developer had made onOptionsItemSelected **final**. I removed it and tried overriding it again only to find that the product was that whenever I press the button nothing happens. Nothing at all.

Any idea on how I would go about using the darvds_ribbonmenu library along with actionbarsherlock?

Comment: Check whether you extends **SherlockFragmentActivity** if you extend it you can Override

Comment: Please read more than just the title of my question.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Turns out that when using ABS you will need to specify the namespace of MenuItem to make sure that you're overriding the correct method. My solution was as follows :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) 
{
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Log.d("item ID : ", "onOptionsItemSelected Item ID" + id);
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        rbmView.toggleMenu();

        return true;

    } else {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just switch your imports. The superclass method with the `android.view.MenuItem` parameter is `final` to prevent your from overriding the wrong one.

Answer (score 17):

Change `import android.view.MenuItem;` to `import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;`. Otherwise, you're just using an entirely different `MenuItem` than the one you're importing.