# onOptionsItemSelected isn't picking the right clicked menu item

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following code in my activity:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
....
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Save")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.action_create).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.action_search)
            .setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    menu.add("Refresh")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_refresh)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Got click: " + item.getItemId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
}
```

However, doesn't matter if I click `save` `search` or `refresh` all I see on the screen is: `Got click 0`

I would expect different `id`'s for each item clicked.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock?

Comment: Yes, I am. Is the behavior different?

Comment: I had that problem before. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10910315/362298

Comment: hmm My imports match actionbarsherlock. So that isn't the problem

Comment: Hmm, another idea: Since you are creating the items programatically, maybe you need to define the ids yourself? Try calling `setId()` on each item in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: There isn't any method like `setId()` that I can call for menu item. And yeah, I'm creating them programmatically, they are not in my layout

Comment: Sorry, use this instead when adding the menu: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29 You can set the id there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal thing to do is to define the `Menu` and its items in xml as a resource - then you can define your own id's to the items. [Here's the android developer guide on how to do it with xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml).

Another quick fix is to not use the id in `onOptionsItemSelected()` and instead use [`MenuItem.getTitle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getTitle%28%29) which you have defined (i.e "Save", "Search", "Refresh").

Comment: great. title will work for me. I was following this sample: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/ContextMenus.java#L49

Answer (score 0):

Follow this struction in the onOptionsItemSelected

```
        case R.id.your_case_name
        //What you want it to do such as a toast
        return true;
```